# How to filter only specific URL with intent filter

Tags: android, intentfilter

I want to filter specific URL : http://gaapa.cz/mobile/*

But this filter is fired on every URl - ehta's wrong with that?

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="gaapa.cz"
                android:path="/mobile/.*"
                android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to either use path, `pathPrefix`, or `pathPattern`, according to [the docs here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path)

In your case, either `pathPattern` or `pathPrefix` will work,

```
pathPattern="mobile/*"
```

or

```
pathPrefix="mobile"
```

However, that does not explain why your filter is matching all URIs. it should be matching none since path does not understand "*". i suspect there is something added / missing from somewhere else in your code.

Comment: One of my intent filters was missing host so path was ignored

Comment: What happens if i want to make a filter for the following url:
http://gaapa.cz/#/aaa

I tried to change pathPrefix or pathPattern to "/#/*" or "#/" and it didn't work

Comment: hash is a reserved character. if you want to use it in a URL you need to encode it (%23).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<data android:host="gaapa.cz"
      android:pathprefix="mobile/"
      android:scheme="http" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
<data android:host="gaapa.cz"
      android:path="mobile"
      android:pathPattern="*"
      android:scheme="http" />
```

Comment: Hmm... android:path="mobile" won't work as it requires a leading "/". Example: android:path="/mobile".