# Android getting request of opening some website in browser to my app

Tags: android, url, redirect, browser, request

can I get the url or request of opening some website as URL is typed or entered in my app. I am implementing parental control. So I just want to block some websites from my app. So can I get the request in my app as user hits any URL in any Browser? Is there any way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add this :

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
});
```

Comment: Alexandre, want URL from Not webview, but from any browser.

Comment: So instead use this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761123/how-to-filter-only-specific-url-with-intent-filter

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening your website into a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) into your android app, you can block it with the [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideKeyEvent%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) callback:

```
mView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      (put here your conditions to block or let load an url)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to block some websites going to open in any browser.

Comment: Then return true only if you want to block the url, else false!