# I want my app to be in the "open with" browser section

Tags: android

If someone clicks on a link it says 'open with' and you can choose between 'Firefox,Chrome...'
How I can put my app there and if someone clicks on my app name ... my app gets started with a parameter which contains this link.

I'm sorry if this is the wrong section.

Comment: Not sure but can help you
Refer this [open here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152838/why-isnt-my-app-on-the-list-of-apps-to-open-txt-file)

Comment: have you heard of intentFilter before? do a little search and phrase your question about it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `<intent-filter>`

**DESCRIPTION:**
Specifies the types of intents that an activity, service, or broadcast receiver can respond to. An intent filter declares the capabilities of its parent component — what an activity or service can do and what types of broadcasts a receiver can handle. It opens the component to receiving intents of the advertised type, while filtering out those that are not meaningful for the component.
Most of the contents of the filter are described by its `<action>`, `<category>`, and `<data>` sub elements.

Here is an example

```
<a href="http://stg.bbc.in/press-rel/abc.html">click me!</a>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml` looks like this:

```
 <activity
    android:name=".DashBoard"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_dash_board"
    android:exported="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <data
            android:host="www.bbc.in"
            android:pathPrefix="/"
            android:scheme="https" />
        <data
            android:host="www.stg.bbc.in"
            android:pathPrefix="/"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Note**: Order of the intent flags might cause a problem so use like above

"I suggest you simply make another `<intent-filter>` with the new sub elements in that tag to avoid the problems" look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app)

Comment: `href="market://`??? That link will not be catched by a http scheme intent-filter i think.

Comment: that will start up the Android Market that points to google play search bar real link will be https://play.google.com/store/search?q=market%3A%2F%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dpname%3Acom.nytimes.android&c=apps&hl=en  , same thing you can find if you type market://search?q=pname:com.nytimes.android on google play search :P

Comment: Can be. But OP wants his app to be in the list with a http:// href. No idea why you come up with market. Its confusing.

Comment: Thanks. `android:host="www.bbc.in"` ?? Why that? What does it do? Wont it restrict to that host only? OP did not ask for that. Confusing.

Comment: thank you for your help but how I can call my app with the url as parameter

Comment: @Akin Unknown have a look here ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9761241/5188159 is that what you want

Comment: I just see that everyone misunderstood me...my fault  I had to ask with pictures...but good to know what I just learned ! It's important for my future programming

Comment: [link](http://i0.wp.com/gwhaleapk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Open-with.jpg) I wanted my app to appear there if people open a url for example in google...it asks me to open it with 'Firefox' 'Chrome' bla bla...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following **`<intent-filter>`** to the Activity (which will open in your app) definition in the manifest file.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

The **`<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`** is optional and is only used to consume default intents.

Comment: also thank you, how I can now commit url as parameter for my app ? My app dooes something with this url. thanks in advance !

Comment: When your activity is started, you will get the URL that started this intent in the data of the Intent.

Comment: Let me know if you want me to elaborate on that, if you still haven't been able to figure out the solution.